# How can I classify a dataset after one-hot encoding the target class?

Tags: python, testing, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I want to Classify a dataset with [kernel machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz5NT.jpg). The Target-Class has 5 different values and I want to one-hot encoding it. After that I have 5 Target-Columns. I do the Training 5 times, one time per Target-Column. Now I want to classify a new sample. I classify the Sample 5 times using the 5 Trainig-model I got. At the end I look which Prediction has the maximum value over the 5 predictions and then I classify the sample according to the Class with the maximum prediction.
I am not sure that I am doing the right thing. How can I do that in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does kernel machine mean?
If it only support binary classification task, you are right to train 5 times and predict by the maximum value.
While, there are a lot alogithms supporting multi-class classification task.
Yon can just train 1 time for 5-targets by multi-class classifier.

Comment: @Ng_Ginger thank you for your answer. Kernel machine (or kernel method) is not very common way for classification but I have to use it for academic reasons. It use kernel function to get kernel matrix from the training data we have, then we have to solve system of equations (I added photo to my post. you can see it) to get the alphas and use it to make prediction for test data.

I have the same Problem posted when I work with SVM too. I classify the model 5 times but I don't know how to make prediction at the end.

Comment: I think you adopted the one versus rest(OVR) strategy, choosing the the class with the maximum prediction is right.